# How to make a background strech the width of the screen?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

For some reason `<div class="h-screen bg-gradient-to-br from-green-400 to-indigo-600">` appears with a white line on the top on desktop:
[image]

it also looks like this on repl (see below_, although can't reproduce using chrome.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial assumption would be that you're getting caught out by margin collapsing. There's an unintuitive situation that occurs with the margins on the first and last child of an element.

In your case, I'd assume that your immediate child element has a top margin which is creating that white gap at the top of the page.

You can solve that problem by setting your container to `display: flow-root`. Tailwind gives you the `.flow-root` class for that.

```
<div class="flow-root h-screen bg-gradient-to-br from-green-400 to-indigo-600">
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, changing `h-screen` to `min-h-screen` seems to fix the scrolling problem as well